# Read .enc or other capture file formats in Scapy Python

Tags: python, pcap, scapy

I am currently working with Scapy and encounter the error:

```
NameError: global name 'Scapy_Exception' is not defined
```

I have 2 options:
To either catch the error and convert the capture file into pcap on the fly using:

```
tshark -F libpcap -w <outfile> -r <infile>
```

or have scapy read capture files in other format.
Can I know:

1. How do I catch Scapy_Exception?
2. How to read capture files in scapy other than the .pcap format?
3. Which of the above options will be better?

Thanks!

Comment: This is what happens when I try:


`try:
    pkts=rdpcap('/home/krish/Desktop/captures/invalid_for_scapy/dicom_42.cap')
except scapy.error.Scapy_Exception as msg:
    print msg`

`NameError: global name 'Scapy_Exception' is not defined`

Comment: First time ever that a questions taking so long to be answered on SO, I guess.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after playing around a little bit, I added the line

`from scapy.error import Scapy_Exception`  in the file utils.py and ran my program.

It catches the error now if I do:

```
try:
   ...:     pkts = rdpcap('./ms_dns.enc')
   ...: except Scapy_Exception as msg:
   ...:     print msg, "Hi there!!"
   ...: 
         Not a pcap capture file (bad magic) Hi there!!
```

So now I can catch the error and convert the file on the fly and use it.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you fix the error about the invalid pcap file? I have generated a file via tshark but I get the same error.

Comment: I cannot comment here with my complete code (it says 67 characters too long). Basically, I catch the scapy_exception, then convert the file to a pcap format using the command in my question. Then I read this file rather than the original file and it should succeed. If it doesn't then the capture file could not be converted!